# SSRS Pie Chart Shrinks on tablix column visibility

Tags: excel, reporting-services, pie-chart

I really hope someone will be able to assist me.  I am struggling with my pie charts and Tablix.  When I export my report to excel and the column groups are set to hidden then my pie charts are distorted.  Is there a setting somewhere that I am not aware of?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can separate the charts to another page/sheet.

Comment: You're not missing anything, it's just a limitation of Excel renderer. The charts are contained in a fixed number of cells based on the report design. In this case it looks like it's in the same column group as the month. When the additional columns are hidden Excel can only fit the chart in the remaining visible cell.